# Fatal error: Call to a member function escapeString() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\results.php on line 17

Tags: php, mysql

Error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function escapeString() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\results.php on line 17

Line 17:

```
$searchterm=$db->escapeString($_GET['searchterm']);
```

It is called in mysql.php

```
public function escapeString($value){

return mysql_escape_string($value);

}
```

I am using MySQL on localhost.

Comment: Ensure that `$db` is indeed an object, as the error message states that it is not.

Comment: It sure is. It's the database name.

Comment: Note that mysql_escape_string is deprecated and you should be using `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead. m_e_s() is vulnerable to character set manipulation and can allow injection attacks to leak through.

Comment: I added mysql_real_escape_string and it still does it.

Answer (score 1):

Your $db variable is not set correctly. It's likely that the connection failed or something else went wrong.

Do this on the line right before 17:

```
var_dump($db); exit;
```

Chances are it will be null or false or some other non-object value indicating that the connection failed. To help more, we'd need to know more about what database connection you're attempting to make (mysql, mysqli, PDO, etc).

Comment: This pops up now: NULL. It is MySQL.

Comment: @Ethan That means the variable is `null`, not an object as you expect it to be. Without seeing more code, we cannot tell you how to fix that.

Comment: @Ethan: The code you pasted below in pastebin seems to indicate you're connecting and setting that to $con and then using $db and calling methods on that. It appears that you're mixing database code from procedural mysql_* stuff and object oriented stuff.  What is the contents of mysql.php?

Comment: @Ethan: There's some serious problems with how the class (MySQL) is built. Nothing in there is really going to do anything to help you out, at least not as it stands now. The code in the pastebin to mike and the code above do not seem to match up with what's on line 17. Without several more methods added, the MySQL class is useless. I would look at mysql_query (http://php.net/mysql_query) and use that and the mysql_real_escape_string directly unless you know how to make the MySQL class useful. It is beyond the scope of this question though, I think.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you avoid errors:

```
if ( is_object($db) && isset($_GET['searchterm']) ) {
  $searchterm=$db->escapeString($_GET['searchterm']);
}
```

We will need more code if you're having problems setting one of the above items.

Comment: Like what more would you need?

My Whole results.php: http://pastebin.com/REBrqzLY

Comment: @Ethan And where is your `$db` variable supposed to be coming from there?

Comment: @deceze Actually, it's not coming from anywhere. What would I declare in the command? $db = ??;

Comment: @Ethan I think you need to go back to basics and try to actually understand what you're doing. On one hand you're connecting to the database using old `mysql_` functions, on the other you seem to have some DB class which you're never *instantiating*. Please, follow a decent tutorial or book that explains everything coherently, don't mix and match stuff.