# Random countRows error?

Tags: php

So I'm coming up with this error, and it is:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function countRows() on a non-object in 
              C:\xampp\htdocs\results.php on line 22
```

But it is weird, because on line 22 it is:

```
$find = strip_tags ( $find );
```

Lines 20-30:

```
        $find = strtolower ( $find );
        $find = strip_tags ( $find );
        $find = trim ( $find );

        $results = mysql_query ( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE type='$type' AND 
                                 price='$price' AND name='$name'" );

        while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_array ( $results ) ) {

                echo "<table>";
                "<tr>";
```

Anyone mind helping?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at `C:\xampp\htdocs\results.php`?

Comment: see if you have properly called the function `countRows()` in the previous lines...

Comment: I am 100% positive.

@PsyCoder, my whole results.php: http://pastebin.com/ZKWTiWXt

Comment: You don't use `countRows()` anywhere in that file... Can you reproduce this at will?

Comment: @MikeB I don't even have countRows() declared in there..

Comment: I know -- I said that. You're either looking at the wrong file, or an old error message that refers to a line/method that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/9880481/668008

Comment: Are you repeatedly getting the error when you try to run the file? If not then I agree with @MIkeB. If so, try deleting some lines to see if the line number changes, etc.

Comment: Hmm, weird. The error is gone. :L When I search nothing comes up? o.o